# Playwright: Hide skipped tests in reporter

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

When using skippable tests in `Playwright`, e.g.

```
test('someSkippableTest', async ({ page, browserName }) => {
  test.skip(browserName === 'firefox');
  // Actual test
});
```

the reporter "list" will show skipped test. The output will then look something like this:

```
✓  1 [chromium] › SomeTestFolder\TestFileName.spec.ts:11:9 › TestGroupName › someSkippableTest (3.3s)
-  2 [firefox] › SomeTestFolder\TestFileName.spec.ts:11:9 › TestGroupName › someSkippableTest
✓  4 [webkit] › SomeTestFolder\TestFileName.spec.ts:11:9 › TestGroupName › someSkippableTest (3.6s)
```

I am only interested in successful or failed tests.

How to hide/suppress the reporting on skipped tests?

Comment: have you had a look at the filtering options ? 

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-ui-mode#filtering-tests

Comment: @Makusium: I do not stand to benefit from debugging tests visually, so I'd use something like:
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#filtering-tests
In both cases: Tests are filtered to not be executed at all, which is not what I want. I want those omitted which are skipped.